# Adding Multiple Jcomponents to a Jframe and calling repaint on all components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint, jcomponent

I have questions regarding JFrames and Jcomponents.

- Firstly, Can we add multiple Jcomponents 
  to a JFrame?
- Secondly, if we do add multiple jcomponents to a JFrame then how do we repaint all of them when we want to do so ?

Comment: Generally, repainting a parent container will cause it to paint it's children as well

Comment: I think more context is needed. Repainting is done mostly automatically, and its rare that you would want to repaint the whole component hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You're always going to have a tree structure in your UI, because JFrame is the root of it.  So yes, you can have multiple components but they will be siblings in a parent.  Use that parent (eith the JFrame or its content pane) as the target for your repainting calls, and it should propagate through the entire UI.